# PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: - ipython-notebook

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, anaconda, graphlab, anaconda3

I'm new to Anaconda and Python. I have set up a virtual environment in Anaconda named "**gl-env**".

- gl-env Python version has set to 2.7
- pip version is set to 9.0.1

I am doing a assignment which requires it to run Jupyter notebook in this environment.

```
(gl-env) C:\Users\SHIVAKUMAR>conda install ipython-notebook
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - ipython-notebook

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page
```

I don't know much about Anaconda. What can I try next?

Comment: The package is called `notebook` in conda's package index. `conda install notebook`

Answer (score -1):

```
(gl-env) C:\Users\SHIVAKUMAR>conda install jupyter notebook
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it's better to include an explanation on how your code addresses the OP's issue. This way, future visitors can learn from your post, & apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. High quality, complete answers reinforce this idea, and are more likely to be upvoted. These features, plus the requirement that all posts be self-contained, are some strengths of SO as a platform that differentiate SO from forums. You can `edit` to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.